# Range over characters in Python

Tags: python, range, character

Is there a way to range over characters? Something like this:

```
for c in xrange( 'a', 'z' ):
    print c
```

Comment: If you just want the English alphabet, there's `import string`, `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 137):

This is a great use for a custom generator:

**Python 3:**

```
def char_range(c1, c2):
    """Generates the characters from `c1` to `c2`, inclusive."""
    for c in range(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)
```

then:

```
for c in char_range('a', 'z'):
    print(c)
```

---

**Python 2:**

```
def char_range(c1, c2):
    """Generates the characters from `c1` to `c2`, inclusive."""
    for c in xrange(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)
```

then:

```
for c in char_range('a', 'z'):
    print c
```

Comment: Beautiful! For anyone who's going to copy this, keep in mind that range(1,3) iterates values 1 and 2 (and not three), but char_range('a','c') will iterate 'a', 'b' and 'c'!

Comment: You could add the optional step arg too: `def char_range(c1, c2, step=1)` ... `ord(c1), ord(c2)+1, step`

Comment: @wjandrea, doesn't quite work for negative steps, eg `char_range('g','a',-1)` gives `['g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c']`

Comment: @alan Nice catch! Looks like that's the fault of the +1 on `ord(c2)`. So replace `ord(c2)+1` with `ord(c2) + (1 if step > 0 else -1)`. Though for clarity's sake you might want to factor that out of the `range()` call.

Comment: The problem with doing that, is that to generate a-z, you will need to know which character comes after z. Not especially comfortable. Probably better to avoid the name «range» (use closedrange or inclusiverange instead ?)

Comment: @Razzle Shazi : This is not something defined by python but in his code. I just told, that since range generally excludes the last position, using the word range in the function name might be a misleading choice.

Answer (score 109):

```
import string
for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print char
```

See [string constants](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) for the other possibilities, including uppercase, numbers, locale-dependent characters, all of which you can join together like `string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase` if you want all of the characters in multiple sets.

Answer (score 27):

You have to convert the characters to numbers and back again.

```
for c in xrange(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    print chr(c) # resp. print unicode(c)
```

For the sake of beauty and readability, you can wrap this in a generator:

```
def character_range(a, b, inclusive=False):
    back = chr
    if isinstance(a,unicode) or isinstance(b,unicode):
        back = unicode
    for c in xrange(ord(a), ord(b) + int(bool(inclusive)))
        yield back(c)

for c in character_range('a', 'z', inclusive=True):
    print(chr(c))
```

This generator can be called with `inclusive=False` (default) to imitate Python's usual bhehaviour to exclude the end element, or with `inclusive=True` (default) to include it. So with the default `inclusive=False`, `'a', 'z'` would just span the range from `a` to `y`, excluding `z`.

If any of `a`, `b` are unicode, it returns the result in unicode, otherwise it uses `chr`.

It currently (probably) only works in Py2.

Comment: You can hide this in a generator: see my answer.

Comment: You mean you like it better with the ord's and chr's in your face?  And if you had to do this more than once you'd duplicate it in each place?  Odd..

Comment: so I had better said 'that looks better' than 'this looks better'.

Answer (score 12):

There are other good answers here (personally I'd probably use string.lowercase), but for the sake of completeness, you could use [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [chr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) on the lower case ascii values:

```
for c in map(chr, xrange(97, 123)):
   print c
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have a short fixed list of characters, just use Python's treatment of strings as lists.

```
for x in 'abcd':
    print x
```

or

```
[x for x in 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 10):

I like an approach which looks like this:

```
base64chars = list(chars('AZ', 'az', '09', '++', '//'))
```

It certainly can be implemented with a lot of more comfort, but it is quick and easy and very readable.

## Python 3

Generator version:

```
def chars(*args):
    for a in args:
        for i in range(ord(a[0]), ord(a[1])+1):
            yield chr(i)
```

Or, if you like list comprehensions:

```
def chars(*args):
    return [chr(i) for a in args for i in range(ord(a[0]), ord(a[1])+1)]
```

The first yields:

```
print(chars('ĀĈ'))
<generator object chars at 0x7efcb4e72308>
print(list(chars('ĀĈ')))
['Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ']
```

while the second yields:

```
print(chars('ĀĈ'))
['Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ']
```

It is really convenient:

```
base64chars = list(chars('AZ', 'az', '09', '++', '//'))
for a in base64chars:
   print(repr(a),end='')
print('')
for a in base64chars:
   print(repr(a),end=' ')
```

outputs

```
'A''B''C''D''E''F''G''H''I''J''K''L''M''N''O''P''Q''R''S''T''U''V''W''X''Y''Z''a''b''c''d''e''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''n''o''p''q''r''s''t''u''v''w''x''y''z''0''1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''+''/'
'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J' 'K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P' 'Q' 'R' 'S' 'T' 'U' 'V' 'W' 'X' 'Y' 'Z' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '+' '/'
```

Why the `list()`?  Without `base64chars` might become a generator (depending on the implementation you chose) and thus can only be used in the very first loop.

## Python 2

Similar can be archived with Python 2.  But it is far more complex if you want to support Unicode, too.  To encourage you to stop using Python 2 in favor of Python 3 I do not bother to provide a Python 2 solution here ;)

> Try to avoid Python 2 today for new projects.  Also try to port old projects to Python 3 first before extending them - in the long run it will be worth the effort!

Proper handling of Unicode in Python 2 is extremely complex, and it is nearly impossible to add Unicode support to Python 2 projects if this support was not build in from the beginning.

Hints how to backport this to Python 2:

- Use `xrange` instead of `range`
- Create a 2nd function (`unicodes`?) for handling of Unicode:

  - Use `unichr` instead of `chr` to return `unicode` instead of `str`
  - Never forget to feed `unicode` strings as `args` to make `ord` and array subscript work properly

Answer (score 5):

```
for character in map(   chr, xrange( ord('a'), ord('c')+1 )   ):
   print character
```

prints:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# generating 'a to z' small_chars.
small_chars = [chr(item) for item in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]
# generating 'A to Z' upper chars.
upper_chars = [chr(item).upper() for item in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]
```

Answer (score 5):

For Uppercase Letters:

```
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    print(chr(i))
```

For Lowercase letters:

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    print(chr(i))
```

Comment: When printing only Range Value that will return only Unicode values of characters, After typecasting to chr() that will return the proper character

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from the top post above, I came up with this :

```
map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @ned-batchelder's answer here, I'm amending it a bit for `python3`

```
def char_range(c1, c2):
    """Generates the characters from `c1` to `c2`, inclusive."""
    """Using range instead of xrange as xrange is deprecated in Python3""" 
    for c in range(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)
```

Then same thing as in Ned's answer:

```
for c in char_range('a', 'z'):
    print c
```

Thanks Ned!

Answer (score 1):

i had the same need and i used this :

```
chars = string.ascii_lowercase
range = list(chars)[chars.find('a'):chars.find('k')+1]
```

Hope this will Help Someone

Comment: This is a good idea and was elegant for my application, something like: `for c in string.ascii_uppercase` (note: the OP has a range end "bug").

Answer (score 0):

Use "for count in range" and chr&ord:

```
print [chr(ord('a')+i) for i in range(ord('z')-ord('a'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
for c in [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z'))]:
    print c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (operates like range - add 1 to stop if you want stop to be inclusive)

```
>>> import string
>>> def crange(arg, *args):
...     """character range, crange(stop) or crange(start, stop[, step])"""
...     if len(args):
...         start = string.ascii_letters.index(arg)
...         stop = string.ascii_letters.index(args[0])
...     else:
...         start = string.ascii_letters.index('a')
...         stop = string.ascii_letters.index(arg)
...     step = 1 if len(args) < 2 else args[1]
...     for index in range(start, stop, step):
...         yield string.ascii_letters[index]
...
>>> [_ for _ in crange('d')]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
>>> [_ for _ in crange('d', 'g')]
['d', 'e', 'f']
>>>
>>> [_ for _ in crange('d', 'v', 3)]
['d', 'g', 'j', 'm', 'p', 's']
>>>
>>> [_ for _ in crange('A', 'G')]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex the range of characters is, a regular expression may be convenient:

```
import re
import string

re.findall("[a-f]", string.printable)
# --> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

re.findall("[n-qN-Q]", string.printable)
# --> ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
```

This works around the pesky issue of accidentally including the punctuation characters in between numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters in the ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

I stumped into this problem a while ago, and I wrote [a package](https://pypi.org/project/character-range/) to do exactly this:

```py
from character_range import CharacterInterval

for char in CharacterInterval('a', 'e'):
  print(char)  # 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'

# Unicode too:
for char in CharacterInterval('\u0100', '\u0110'):
  print(char)  # '\u0100', '\u0101', ..., '\u0109', '\u0110'
```

There's also `ByteInterval`:

```py
from character_range import CharacterInterval

for byte in ByteInterval(b'\x7E', b'\x82'):
  print(byte)  # b'\x7E', b'\x7F', b'\x80', b'\x81', b'\x82'
```

You can also iterate over multicharacter strings:

```py
from character_range import StringRange, CharacterMap

for string in StringRange('zy', 'aab', CharacterMap.ASCII_LOWERCASE):
  print(string)  # 'zy', 'zz', 'aaa', 'aab'
```

Naturally, there's a `bytes` equivalent:

```py
from character_range import ByteRange, ByteMap

for string in ByteRange(b'zy', b'aab', ByteMap.ASCII_LOWERCASE):
  print(string)  # b'zy', b'zz', b'aaa', b'aab'
```

Find these names hard to remember? Not to worry, there's the titular function `character_range`. Currently there is no shorthands for the maps, but it's on the track.

```py
from character_range import character_range, CharacterMap:

character_range('a', 'z', CharacterMap.ASCII_LOWERCASE)
character_range(b'a', b'z', ByteMap.ASCII_LOWERCASE)
```

These classes' `__iter__()`s are implemented as generators. That is, an instance would yield its elements one by one, lazily and only on demand.

See [the docs](https://character-range.readthedocs.io/) for an API reference. Note that this package has just been released (as of writing); it is not stable and the API may change drastically in the future. Always specify the version in your dependencies.

Comment: an interesting approach, although I'd be inclined to use Unicode sets and for language specific support leverage of exemplars as Unicode sets.

Comment: @Andj You can construct the maps yourselves. Suggestions for prebuilt maps are also welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, I rarely need simple sets of contiguous characters. More often I am working with intersections so something like `[[\p{LL}]&[\p{Latin}]]` is a more compact notation for me, the intersection of all lowercase characters and all Latin characters. But I can see where your code would be useful to use. Just at times I would find Unicode sets more appropriate.