# Inputing a sentence and counting each individual letter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically I need the program to count how many times each letter is used in a sentence. 
The only thing I've found is this, and it's ugly:

```
from collections import Counter
str = "Mary had a little lamb"
counter = Counter(str)
print counter['a']
print counter['b']
print counter['c']
print counter['d']
print counter['e']
print counter['f']
#etc to z
```

Is there a simpler way to do this????

Comment: The code you mention is actually simpler than what you'd get in most other languages (thanks to the helpful `collections` module). Unless you're wondering how to write a `for` cycle... is that it?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538374/1454048). You'll need to write the counting code yourself, but that'll get you started.

Comment: Not sure which aspect you think is ugly.  The counting operation is just two lines (import Counter class, then create Creater instance).  Is it the succession of `print` statements that you find ugly?  Of course there are a million different ways to use/present the information once you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand you:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> s = "Mary had a little lamb"
>>> counts = Counter(s.lower())
>>> for letter in ascii_lowercase:
...     print letter, counts[letter]
...     
a 4
b 1
c 0
[...]
x 0
y 1
z 0
```

Note that I lowercased the string so that `m` would give 2; if you don't want that, remove `.lower()` and use `string.ascii_letters` instead.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `counts["non-existing key"]` returns `0`. I didn't know that before and would have expected a `KeyError`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: yeah, even though `Counter` isn't a subclass of `defaultdict`, it behaves like one in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through all the lowercase letters, and print out the counts for each:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sentence = "Mary had a little lamb"
>>> counter = Counter(sentence)
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> for letter in ascii_lowercase:
...     print '{} = {}'.format(letter, counter[letter])
a = 4
b = 1
c = 0
d = 1
e = 1
f = 0
g = 0
h = 1
i = 1
j = 0
k = 0
l = 3
m = 1
n = 0
o = 0
p = 0
q = 0
r = 1
s = 0
t = 2
u = 0
v = 0
w = 0
x = 0
y = 1
z = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to print information about the characters that are actually in the string, a simple way would be to do

```
for key in sorted(counter.keys()):
    print("{0} appears {1} times.".format(key, counter[key]))
```

Result:

```
  appears 4 times.
M appears 1 times.
a appears 4 times.
b appears 1 times.
d appears 1 times.
e appears 1 times.
h appears 1 times.
i appears 1 times.
l appears 3 times.
m appears 1 times.
r appears 1 times.
t appears 2 times.
y appears 1 times.
```

Note that the space character is counted, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
str = "Mary had a little lamb"
counter = Counter(str)
for c in set(str):
    print '%s -> %d' % (c, counter[c])
```

Comment: You use spaces instead of backticks to codify blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
from collections import Counter
str = "Mary had a little lamb"
counter = Counter(str)
for letter in string.lowercase:
    print counter[letter]
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001144/range-over-character-in-python), it'll give you an example of how to create a range of characters. Then simply use the foreach loop :

```
for item in letters_a_to_z:
    print counter[item]
```