# Count how many times each letter appears in a text sample

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I need a function that counts how many times each individual letter appears in a string. It has to count capitals and lowercase as the same letter. I sort of did it, but its not exactly pretty.

```
def lmao(x):

    aye=x.count("a")
    Aye=x.count("A")
    bye=x.count("b")
    Bye=x.count("B")
    cye=x.count("c")
    Cye=x.count("C")
    dye=x.count("d")
    Dye=x.count("D")
    Eye=x.count("E")
    eye=x.count("e")
    Fye=x.count("F")
    fye=x.count("f")
    Gye=x.count("G")
    gye=x.count("g")
    Hye=x.count("H")
    hye=x.count("h")
    Iye=x.count("I")
    iye=x.count("i")
    Jye=x.count("J")
    jye=x.count("j")
    Kye=x.count("K")
    kye=x.count("k")
    Lye=x.count("L")
    lye=x.count("l")
    Mye=x.count("M")
    mye=x.count("m")
    Nye=x.count("N")
    nye=x.count("n")
    Oye=x.count("O")
    oye=x.count("o")
    Pye=x.count("P")
    pye=x.count("P")
    Qye=x.count("Q")
    qye=x.count("q")
    rye=x.count("r")
    Rye=x.count("R")
    sye=x.count("s")
    Sye=x.count("S")
    tye=x.count("t")
    Tye=x.count("T")
    uye=x.count("u")
    Uye=x.count("U")
    Vye=x.count("V")
    vye=x.count("v")
    Wye=x.count("W")
    wye=x.count("w")
    Xye=x.count("X")
    xye=x.count("x")
    Yye=x.count("Y")
    yye=x.count("y")
    Zye=x.count("Z")
    zye=x.count("z")
    killme=(aye+Aye,bye+Bye,cye+Cye,Dye+dye,Eye+eye,Fye+fye,Gye+gye,Hye+hye,Iye+iye,jye+Jye,Kye+kye,Lye+lye,Mye+mye,Nye+nye,Oye+oye,Pye+pye,Qye+qye,rye+Rye,sye+Sye,Tye+tye,uye+Uye,Vye+vye,Wye+wye,xye+Xye,Yye+yye,Zye+zye)
    return killme
```

So yeah, thats the disaster that I came up with. Is there any way to shorten this process?

Comment: I like the name of your final variable. Here's some related read [Count occurrence of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1155617) and [Alphabet range python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16060899)

Comment: Could use a dict and just use each letter you find as a key and use the value for a count of how many you seen. Then add up all values in dict.

Answer (score 5):

Use `collections.Counter` https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects

```
from collections import Counter    
counter = Counter(mystr.lower())
```

will give you all occurrences of each letter, ignoring case

Comment: I suppose he wants the count of letters that are not in the string as well.

Comment: @VincentSavard that's no problem, the counter returns 0 by default when it does not find a key.

Comment: @timgeb: I meant in the return tuple.

Comment: @VincentSavard: True.  It's possible to generate all letters using ord() and range() as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001144/range-over-character-in-python.  OP can use this to see what's not in the counter

Comment: @TomNash: the OP said "it has to count capitals and lowercase as the same letter"

Comment: You can always `return tuple(counter[c] for c in string.lowercase)` to return an equivalent tuple as the OP, and as @timgeb pointed out `0` would be in place for any non-existent character.

Answer (score 2):

To return exactly what you've requested:

```
import string
def lmao(x):
    return tuple(x.lower().count(c) for c in string.lowercase)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
def counter(text):
    count_list = []
    for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        count_list.append(text.lower().count(char))
    return tuple(count_list)

print(counter("Helllo123"))
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use counter together with a dictionary comprehension to get the count of each letter.

```
import string
from collections import Counter
```

For an alpha sorted tuple,

```
def count_letter_tuples(sentence):
    return tuple(Counter(sentence.lower()).get(c, 0) for c in string.ascii_lowercase)

>>> count_letter_tuples("Some Big Sentence")
(0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Or for a dictionary response:

```
def count_letters(sentence):
    return {c: Counter(sentence.lower()).get(c, 0) for c in string.ascii_lowercase}

>>> count_letters("Some Big Sentence")
{'a': 0,
 'b': 1,
 'c': 1,
 'd': 0,
 'e': 4,
 'f': 0,
 'g': 1,
 'h': 0,
 'i': 1,
 'j': 0,
 'k': 0,
 'l': 0,
 'm': 1,
 'n': 2,
 'o': 1,
 'p': 0,
 'q': 0,
 'r': 0,
 's': 2,
 't': 1,
 'u': 0,
 'v': 0,
 'w': 0,
 'x': 0,
 'y': 0,
 'z': 0}
```