# 'int' object is not iterable python brute force password

Tags: python, for-loop, zip, brute-force

Even though the syntax all seems correct I'm still thrown an output error, any reason why it throws this on the output? (please ignore my bad indentation).

```
import zipfile
myZip = zipfile.ZipFile("/mydile.zip")
count = 0
for x in range(0,1005310):
   password = count
   count += 1
   try:
      myZip.extractall(pwd = password)
      print(password)
except Exception as e:
      print(e)
print "Sorry, password not found."
```

Comment: pass a string password – `pwd=str(password)` – probably

Comment: @Ryan Yes thank you oversight on my behalf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
count = 0
```

`count` is an integer.

```
password = count
```

`password` is an integer.

```
myZip.extractall(pwd = password)
```

This cannot be right.  `pwd` must have the value of a string.  You can convert it to a string using `str()`

As suggested by [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) this is exactly what you have to do.

```
myZip.extractall(pwd = str(password))
```

You cannot place `str()` anywhere else because up to this point you are performing arithmetic and you cannot do arithmetic on string without converting.

---

Bear in mind that this brute-force method will only work if the password is an integer.  This is highly improbable so you may also want to include characters.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001144/range-over-character-in-python) might be of some use if you decide to do this.