# Generate Range containing string and numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a range between two variables. The variables contain string and number characters.

For example P9160-P9163 or P360-P369.
The P is not constant and could be any character(s)/multiple, but i'm trying to generate a list that would contain all values in between.

i tried with looking at ASCII characters but didn't work for me.

Any thoughts?

```
x = 'P9160'
y = 'P9163'

x = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", x, re.I)
y = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", y, re.I)

for i in range(int(x.groups()[1]), int(y.groups()[1])+1):
    print("{}{}".format(x.groups()[0], i))
```

Comment: Would you please share what you have tried so far? Hit the "edit" button above and paste in the code you've tried and why it does not work. This will help everyone understand the approach(es) you've already taken.

Comment: I did something like this... which seems pretty long
x = 'P9160'
y = 'P9163'

x = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", x, re.I)
y = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", y, re.I)

for i in range(int(x.groups()[1]), int(y.groups()[1])+1):
    print("{}{}".format(x.groups()[0], i))

Comment: @aversalus01 Please [edit] to add details. Comments don't support all the formatting necessary for representing code.

Comment: Could you also [edit] and give an example of what you mean by *"The P is not constant and could be any character(s)/multiple"*?

Comment: What is not constant... The "P" could be any other letter or multiple letters... for example "GX", "XYZ"... etc... so not necessary just one character. I'm just looking for something faster than the above code I supplied

Comment: Please also add more details on the expected output: you say P could also be another letter but the few examples you give all contain only P. Are there a minimum and maximum length?

Comment: No minimum or maximum lengths: Here are examples:
J120-J189, LX8944-LX8945, M8080-M8088.

Comment: @aversalus01 So the letter portion is always capital letters of matching length?

Comment: Related: [range over character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7001144/4518341)

Comment: @aversalus01 So all you want is faster code that generates exactly the same result from your code, correct?

Comment: @KhalidAli, Yes, faster code than what I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a reusable regex pattern, and a generator expression, does certainly improves the code performance.

```py
import re

x = 'P9160'
y = 'P9173'

# resuable regex pattern
regex = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)")

x, y = regex.match(x), regex.match(y)

# generator expression
xy = (x.groups()[0]+str(i) for i in range(int(x.groups()[1]), int(y.groups()[1])+1))

# list of all values from the generator
print(list(xy))
```