# Is there a simple way to iterate over a disjoint range of Excel sheet in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to iterate over a **disjoint range** that has `'A1', 'O1', 'R1:S1'` structure.
There are many workbooks, and there are many rows to iterate in respective sheet of each workbook (say, rows 21, 24, 31:35, 40 of 'Sheet1').
Is there a simple way to iterate over it with openpyxl, or other library?

At the moment I use the following for each row, which is unacceptable.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

sheet = wb['Sheet1']
for cellObj in sheet['A1:S2']:
    for cell in cellObj:
        pass
```

I've failed to find a tip in the documentation.
May be some other library or different approach is applicable in such cases?

Comment: You can do: `for row in (21, 24, (31, 35), 40):` and `values = [cell(row=row, column=col).value for col in (A, O, R, S)]`

Comment: @stovfl, I have some issue with 'str' and 'int'. Should I use some `column_index_from_string` ?

Comment: ***Should I use some `column_index_from_string`?***: Yes, my `(A, O, R, S)` are meant to be `int`.

Comment: `MultiCellRange` sounds like it could be useful.

Comment: @CharlieClark, could you elaborate?

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html#openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is something built-in the library for it, but you might do something like:

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

rows = [21, 24] + list(range(31, 36) + [40]
cols = ["A", "O", "R", "S"]

for row in rows:
    for col in cols:
        cell = sheet[f"{col}{row}"]
```

In this case `R` and `S` are consecutive so there is not much problem. If you had bigger ranges that will be tedious to write manually, check out how to create a [character range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001371/6045800) and use it the same way as in the `rows`.

---

As noted by *stovfl*, the string formatting might be more expensive. As we have the row and col of the cells, we can use the `Worksheet.cell` method with a simple conversion:

```py
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string

...
cols = ["A", "O", "R", "S"]
cols = [column_index_from_string(col) for col in cols]
...
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, col=col)
```

- Of course if you would use integer notation in the first place for the `cols`, no conversion will be needed and the access would be as the last row of code.

Comment: Don't use `sheet["{col}{row}"]` notation, it's slow. You allready have `row`,`col` access the cell direct.

Comment: Thanks @stovfl indeed that might be better apart from a small conversion (as the `cell` method takes integers

Comment: @garej not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I mean, in notation similar to the following wrong expression: `sheet['A1, R1:S1']`

Comment: @garej not that i'm aware of or able to find in the docs. The most is continuos range spreading over multiple rows/cols

Comment: @garej ***`sheet['A1, R1:S1']`***: You can define a function generator, e.g. `def disjoint_range('A1, R1:S1'):` which yields column index according to the given ranges. But you can't use this with `sheet[...]`.